# TCP/IP chat program is sending me mixed messages

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I'm building a simple tcp/ip chat program and I'm having difficulty sending messages separately. If for example I send two messages and both have content larger than the buffer  which can hold 20 characters, 20 characters of the first message is sent and then 20 characters of the next message is sent and then the the rest of the first message and then the rest of the last message. So when I parse and concatenate the strings I get two messages, the beginning of the first message and the beginning of the second and the end of the first and end of the second, respectively. I want to know how to send a message, and queue the next messages until the first message has already been sent. As a side note I'm using asynchronous method calls and not threads.

My code:

Client:

```
protected virtual void Write(string mymessage)
{


               var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mymessage);
               MySocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 
SocketFlags.None,EndSendCallBack, null);

               if (OnWrite != null)
               {
                   var target = (Control) OnWrite.Target;
                   if (target != null && target.InvokeRequired)
                   {
                       target.Invoke(OnWrite, this, new EventArgs());
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       OnWrite(this, new EventArgs());
                   }
               }
        }
```

and the two calls that get mixed:

```
 client.SendMessage("CONNECT",Parser<Connect>.TextSerialize(connect));
  client.SendMessage("BUDDYLIST","");
```

and finally the read  function (I use a number at the beginning of every message to know when the message ends surround by brackets):

```
private void Read(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            string content;
            var buffer = ((byte[]) ar.AsyncState);
            int len = MySocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (len > 0)
            {
                string cleanMessage;
                content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, len);
                if (MessageLength == 0)
                {
                    MessageLength = int.Parse(content.Substring(1, content.IndexOf("]", 1) - 1));
                    cleanMessage = content.Replace(content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("]", 0) + 1), "");
                }
                else
                    cleanMessage = content;

                if(cleanMessage.Length <1)
                {
                    if(MySocket.Connected)
                        MySocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Read), buffer);
                    return;
                }

                MessageLength = MessageLength > cleanMessage.Length? MessageLength - cleanMessage.Length : 0;
                amessage += cleanMessage;

                if(MessageLength == 0)
                {
                    if (OnRead != null)
                    {
                        var e = new CommandEventArgs(this, amessage);
                        Control target = null;
                        if (OnRead.Target is Control)
                            target = (Control)OnRead.Target;
                        if (target != null && target.InvokeRequired)
                            target.Invoke(OnRead, this, e);
                        else
                            OnRead(this, e);
                    }
                    amessage = String.Empty;
                }
                MySocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Read), buffer);
                    return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: TCP does not work with the concept of messages. It gives a stream and nothing more. You need to write a mechanism on top of that to split the stream into messages.

Comment: I have a number in brackets at the beginning of the string to know when the message ends i.e. [3]hey. The problem is I would get [3]h and then [3]y nad then 'ow' and then 'you' if I sent '[3]how' and '[3]' you. That's only if the buffer is 4.

Comment: So you send "[3]how[3]you" and receive "[3]h[3]yowyou"? Sounds implausible to me. But I usually write my network code single threaded. I suspect your threading code isn't written correctly.

Comment: But TCP is allowed to insert packet borders between any bytes in the stream, and it my concat multiple messages too. There is no 1to1 mapping between calls to Send and Receive. The order is conserved though, unless you use threads in an incorrect way.

Comment: This always happens with TCP/IP, it's impossible to know how she feels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP do **not** guarantee that you will receive your entire message in one read. Therefore you need to be able to detect where a message starts and where it ends.

You normally do that by adding some special characters at the end of the message. Or use a length header before the actual message.

You normally do not need to use `BeginSend` in a client. Send should be fast enough and will also reduce complexity. Also, I usually do not use `BeginSend` in servers either unless the server should be really performant.

**Update**

The actual socket implementation will never ever mix your messages, only your code can do that. You cannot send a message by calling multiple sends, since then your messages will be mixed if your application is multi threaded.

In other words, this will not work:

```
_socket.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[" + message.Length + "]"))
_socket.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
```

You have to send everything with one send.

**Update 2**

Your read implementation do not take into account that two messages can come in the same Read. It's most likely that that's the cause to your mixed messages.

If you send:

```
[11]Hello world
[5]Something else
```

They can arrive as:

```
[11]Hello World[5]Some
thing else
```

In other words, part of the second message can arrive in the first `BeginRead`. You should always build a buffer with all received contents (use `StringBuilder`) and remove the handled parts.

Pseudo code:

```
method OnRead
    myStringBuilder.Append(receivedData);
    do while gotPacket(myStringBuilder)
        var length = myStringBuilder.Get(2, 5)
        if (myStringBuilder.Length < 7 + length)
           break;

        var myMessage = myStringBuilder.Get(7, length);
        handle(myMessage);

        myStringBuilder.Remove(0, 7+length);
    loop
end method
```

Do you see what I'm doing? I'm always appending the stringbuilder with the received data and then remove complete messages. I'm using a loop since multiple messages can arrive at once.

Comment: My reply above copied and pasted: 'I have a number in brackets at the beginning of the string to know when the message ends i.e. [3]hey. The problem is I would get [3]h and then [3]y nad then 'ow' and then 'you' if I sent '[3]how' and '[3]' you. That's only if the buffer is 4. '

Comment: I have a mechanism and I know when a message ends, the problem is the mixing of messages.

Comment: I just want to check my understanding of your comments on the problem... Is it that the asynchronous calls are effectively running in different threads so they are taking it in turns to write to the IP stream and thus the messages get confused? I assume the solution then is to have a queue in code to contain the messages and only one thread accessing that. Alternatively I assume that if you use send instead of beginsend it will make it all single threaded (as far s the code we see is concerned) and thus it will just work?

Comment: `BeginSend` will not mix messages even if called simultaneously from a lot of different threads, *as long as the entire message is sent with one `BeginSend`*. If your messages are sent with one BeginSend as with your code sample, the problem is likely the one described in my second update.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a whole message in one send call it will arrive in sequence. You need a delimiter to separate your messages. On the receiving side you need to buffer messages into a buffer. If you are not sending large amounts of data you can allow yourself a bit sloppy, but easy coding to process incoming messages:

```
// Note: Untested pseudocode
buffer += stringDataRead;
while (buffer.Contains("\r\n")) {
  // You may want to compensate for \r\n by doing a -2 here and +2 on next line
  line = buffer.Substring(0, buffer.IndexOf("\r\n"));
  buffer = buffer.Remove(0, line.Length);

  DoSomehingWithThisLine(line);
}
```

No magic required. :)

Comment: I would not use strings for this, memory consumption will be huge in a rather busy server. But +1 for making a clearer sample than mine.